# GroovyScriptEngine locating resources in a web container

Tags: java, groovy

I am looking at using groovy scripts in an existing web application and am busy setting up and configuring the `GroovyScriptEngine`.

What are the "best practices" for managing the scripts in the container ?

1. Should I store them in a database
   and then serve them up to the engine
   via URLs ?
2. I could store them in the
   file system on the server - however
   that seems problematic in Tomcat/JBoss ?

Any suggestions welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate the GroovyScriptEngine with a ResourceConnector implementation of your own. This can use java.lang.Class.getResource to get the script that you embed in the war file.

If you need to be able to dynamically change the script then a database may be a good idea.

Comment: Would you have one GSE for the whole app or are they lightwieght to create ?